# Open only one form in event

Tags: c#, events

When a particular event appears, I want to open a new Form (using ShowDialog), and while this dialog is open, I want to ignore / dequeue all incoming similar events raised.

It's possible? How?

My event method in which I try to manage is like :

```
void barcode_Scanned(object sender, string value)
{
    if(value.StartsWith("d")
    {
        // ShowDialog
    }
}
```

Scenario:

- BarCode Scan
- otherForm.ShowDialog()
- BarCode Scan -> Ignored because dialog already opened
- BarCode Scan -> Ignored because dialog already opened
- otherForm is closed
- BarCode Scan
- otherForm.ShowDialog() -> Possible because previous closed

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* simply use a variable or property, such that:

```
private bool isDialogOpen = false;

void barcode_Scanned(object sender, string value)
{    
    if(value.StartsWith("d") && !isDialogOpen)
    {
        isDialogOpen = true;
        // ShowDialog            
        isDialogOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work because, until the Dialog is open, the events are enqueued and called sequentially, so once the Dialog closed, if a event was raised, dialog will directly be opened instead of be ignored

Answer (score 3):

You could disconnect the event upon receiving a scan and reconnect when you're ready.

```
void barcode_Scanned(object sender, string value)
{
    barcode.Scanned -= barcode_Scanned;

    // do work

    barcode.Scanned += barcode_Scanned;
}
```

Comment: Tried to but not working, it when attaching event again, method will immediatly be launched again if a Scan occurs when unattached...

Comment: @Arnaud F.:  Sounds like your scanner is queuing them for you (in other words, a vendor-specific problem).  There may be an additional property for it to not do that.

Comment: That's the problem I think because I tried all and I observed always this behavior... What a mess...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop everything else doing anything, try opening a Modal Dialog Box, that will stop you from using the other forms while that one is open if that's what you need and/or if it works?